# Не понимаю как заметить нагрузку на диск

Tags: c++, winapi, диск, ресурсы, raii

В общем у меня не было двух последних строчек с Delete, при этом нигде даже на сайте микрософтов нет упоминания, что их нужно писать, память не утекает, ничего не заметно, пока вдруг не начинались дикие лаги и диск 100%. Как это заметить? И нужны ли обе строчки или хватит только одного Delete? Как в VS заметить это?

**Game** - это глобальная переменная HDC

**image** - это глобальный указатель на массив цветов COLORREF

```
void Draw()
{
    HDC memDC = CreateCompatibleDC(Game);
    HBITMAP memBM = CreateBitmap(1920, 1080, 1, 32, image);   
    (HBITMAP)SelectObject(memDC, memBM);
    SetMapMode(memDC, GetMapMode(Game));

    BitBlt(Game, 0, 0, 1920, 1080, memDC, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);

    DeleteObject(memBM);
    DeleteObject(memDC);
}
```

Comment: *"нигде даже на сайте микрософтов нет упоминания, что их нужно писать"* - [офф документация к `CreateBitmap`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-createbitmap) *"When you no longer need the bitmap, call the DeleteObject function to delete it."* Без них память утекает рекой. Кроме того, у этой функции необходимо проверять результат. А то тут вы пытаетесь удалять объект, когда он выбран в контекст.

Comment: а как его надо удалять?

Comment: Перед вызовом DeleteObject необходимо выбрать к контекст что-то другое.

Comment: я проверил и так работает

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> нигде даже на сайте микрософтов нет упоминания, что их нужно писать

Неправду говорите! Описание [`CreateBitmap`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-createbitmap) -

> When you no longer need the bitmap, call the DeleteObject function to delete it.

Описание [`CreateCompatibleDC`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-createcompatibledc):

> When you no longer need the memory DC, call the DeleteDC function. We recommend that you call DeleteDC to delete the DC. However, you can also call DeleteObject with the HDC to delete the DC.

Как заметить? Ну, раз уж у вас тэг С++ - пользуйтесь идиомой RAII - засовывайте `Create...` в конструктор, `Delete...` в деструктор. А так вы организовываете очень неплохую утечку ресурсов.

Мама не зря в детстве (наверняка!) говорила - **попользовался - положи на место!**
Это правило для программиста должно быть таким же непреложным, как и расстегнуть штаны, прежде чем в туалете нужду справлять... :)

Comment: а сейчас, когда я написал удалить все, больше никуда ничего не утекает? Точно?